# Ignore the SQL errors exceptions while inserting and continue the insertion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I had data in one `#table` containig particular rows and I need to insert all those rows into an original database table. I had written the query as below

```
insert into tbl_user select * from #tblExcelData
```

`#tblExcelData` contains multiple rows which are going to insert in `tbl_user`.

But while insertion due to a one-row foreign key exception is fired and after that insertion is stopped.

I want to continue this insertion for other rows. It is ok that the faulty Row which is the reason for the exception is not get inserted but other rows should continue.

Is there any way in SQL Server to do this?

Comment: You can just modify your query a little, to exclude those that are already in the tbl_user.

Comment: TSQL statements are atomic. Either the statement succeeds and all the appropriate rows are affected - or nothing is affected. If you want this level of control, you could use a cursor. SSIS is another option and would allow you to load rows from the excel file to your table and handle the errors individually. Keep in mind that you could many different types of errors - it is not safe to assume that a foreign key problem is the only possible one.

Answer (score 3):

Far as I know, you can't; a DML statement is executed completely or not at all, and in the case of an error it's not at all.

What you can (and should) do, is select only data you *can* insert.

Something like:

```
insert into tbl_user 
select * 
from   #tblExcelData x
inner join tbl_with_FK y
        on y.PK = x.FK
```